# Dual Ultrawide + Built-in Display

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

My work recently provided me with a dual ultrawide dock setup, but I am unable to use both at the same time, in conjunction with my built in display. I have verified various configurations that will work, but I am not sure what is limiting me here. Does the Ubuntu: Gnome GUI have a max horizontal resolution? Is this a know limitation with integrated Intel Graphics (Intel® UHD Graphics 620)?

Working Configs:
(1920x1080)+(3440x1440)
(1920x1080)+(2560x1440)+(2560x1440)
(3440x1440)+(3440x1440)

Not working:
(1920x1080)+(3440x1440)+(3440x1440)

Answer (score 2):

According to Intel own page:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/products/126789/graphics/graphics-for-8th-generation-intel-processors/intel-uhd-graphics-620.html
you're already pushing the limits with the `(1920x1080)+(2560x1440)+(2560x1440)` configuration since it mentions `4096x2304@60Hz` is max of what you should be able to get.

Moreover, it will usually be limited by CPU model itself. See here which explains how some CPUs will not support `4096x2304@60Hz` combination:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000023781/graphics.html

Therefore, I don't think your UHD is able to support combination of two external dual ultrawide monitors + built-in, sorry.